# Trying to understand scipy.signal.kaiserord

Tags: filters, filter-design, lowpass-filter, digital-filters

I am trying to understand [scipy.signal.kaiserord](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.kaiserord.html) example. The example says

> We will use the Kaiser window method to design a lowpass FIR filter
> for a signal that is sampled at 1000 Hz.
>
> We want at least 65 dB rejection in the stop band, and in the pass
> band the gain should vary no more than 0.5%.
> We want a cutoff frequency of 175 Hz, with a transition between the
> pass band and the stop band of 24 Hz. That is, in the band [0, 163],
> the gain varies no more than 0.5%, and in the band [187, 500], the
> signal is attenuated by at least 65 dB.

**Q1:** The example says that we need 65 db rejection in the stop band. So the `ripple` in the `kaiserord` is 65 db. Then it says that in the pass band the gain should vary no more than 0.5%. I do not understand this part. How do we control this variation? In the `kaiserord`, we can only change the rejection in he stop band. Can you please explain this part in more detail?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import kaiserord, firwin, freqz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
fs = 1000.0   
cutoff = 175
width = 24
```

> The Kaiser method accepts just a single parameter to control the pass
> band ripple and the stop band rejection, so we use the more
> restrictive of the two. In this case, the pass band ripple is 0.005,
> or 46.02 dB, so we will use 65 dB as the design parameter.
>
> Use kaiserord to determine the length of the filter and the parameter
> for the Kaiser window.

**Q2:** Here the example says that the method accepts just a single parameter. I suppose refers to the `kaiserord` parameter `ripple`. Then it says that we use the more restrictive of the two. What does this means? Can we quantify this restriction? Then, it says that the band pass ripple is 0.005 or 46.02 db. How can we quantify this using the stop band rejection parameter `ripple?`

```
numtaps, beta = kaiserord(65, width/(0.5*fs))
```

> numtaps 167
>
> beta
> 6.20426
>
> Use firwin to create the FIR filter.

```
taps = firwin(numtaps, cutoff, window=('kaiser', beta), scale=False, fs=fs)
```

> Compute the frequency response of the filter. w is the array of
> frequencies, and h is the corresponding complex array of frequency
> responses.

```
w, h = freqz(taps, worN=8000)
w *= 0.5*fs/np.pi  # Convert w to Hz.
```

> Compute the deviation of the magnitude of the filter’s response from
> that of the ideal lowpass filter. Values in the transition region are
> set to nan, so they won’t appear in the plot.

```
ideal = w < cutoff  # The "ideal" frequency response.
deviation = np.abs(np.abs(h) - ideal)
deviation[(w > cutoff - 0.5*width) & (w < cutoff + 0.5*width)] = np.nan
```

> Plot the deviation. A close look at the left end of the stop band
> shows that the requirement for 65 dB attenuation is violated in the
> first lobe by about 0.125 dB. This is not unusual for the Kaiser
> window method.

**Q3:** I do not understand in which part the requirement for attenuation is violated and why it is 0.125db. Could you please explain it in more detail and mark it in the plot?

```
plt.plot(w, 20*np.log10(np.abs(deviation)))
plt.xlim(0, 0.5*fs)
plt.ylim(-90, -60)
plt.grid(alpha=0.25)
plt.axhline(-65, color='r', ls='--', alpha=0.3)
plt.xlabel('Frequency (Hz)')
plt.ylabel('Deviation from ideal (dB)')
plt.title('Lowpass Filter Frequency Response')
plt.show()
```

Could you please someone address my questions?